# avoid page refresh while loading iframe video javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a scrolling iframe video section in my web page. The problem is the page gets refresh on every iframe load in scroll. I have used the scroller from this site `http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/index.html#toc`. How to avoid page refresh while loading iframe?

Html:

```
<div id="logoParade">
  <div class="scrollWrapper">
    <div class="scrollableArea">
      <div class="product-box" id="test">
        <iframe width="700" height="500" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/QTKM-54zWm4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="product-box" id="test">
        <iframe width="700" height="500" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/QTKM-54zWm4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="product-box" id="test">
        <iframe width="700" height="500" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/QTKM-54zWm4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="product-box" id="test">
        <iframe width="700" height="500" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/QTKM-54zWm4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="product-box" id="test">
        <iframe width="700" height="500" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/QTKM-54zWm4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no refresh taking place on every iframe load, at least not that I know of.
The only problem I see in your HTML is similar ID attributes ("test") which have nothing to do with refresh, just something you should fix too.

I've tested your code with the plugin and it works fine.